# Meshroom Meshing node fails with "Depth map fusion gives an empty result"

Tags: photogrammetry, structure-from-motion, meshroom

I have a photogrammetry pipeline in Meshroom (lightly modified from the default). The pipeline fails on the Meshing node with the error "Depth map fusion gives an empty result."

My StructureFromMotion node found 3,172,414 points from 731 images. My system has only 16 GB of RAM so I reduced Max Input Points on the Meshing node to 5,000,000 and Max Points to 800,000.

Can anyone tell me what the error "Depth map fusion gives an empty result" means, and what can be done to address it?

Comment: I was able to avoid the error by disconnecting inputs to the "Custom Bounding Box" and "Bounding Box Settings" parameters. Both inputs came from another Meshing node that hadn't completed successfully.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work in my case.